# What could be some possible reasons that an employer would refuse to let an employee complete the I-9?

Tags: human-resources

Scenario.

An employer refused to let an employee complete an I-9 on the date of hire, although the employee presented more than the necessary documents (DL, Soc card, birth certificate and passport).  The employer in the Chief Executive position , when pressed, explained that 'no one' ever checks anyways.

The employee  did complete a W-4 on date of hire, and has currently been paid for 4 of the 6 weeks they worked.  The paychecks came in the form of direct deposit to the employee's bank.

The employee asked several times since, and has routinely been denied the request.  The employee then notices that other new hires are being allowed to complete the I-9 on their date of hire.  The employee would like to ask to complete the I-9 as well, but is concerned that the inquiry could result in retaliation.  The employee does not suspect that their employer is concerned about the validity of their citizenship.

The employee has now worked there for over 6 weeks, and has received paychecks through direct deposit.  The employee does not have access to their pay stubs, because it was completed online.

The question is...
What could be some possible reasons that the employer would be motivated to not allow the completion of the I-9 for this employee?

Comment: Did they ask you fill out a form for tax withholding at the very least?

Comment: Worth a read:  https://www.uscis.gov/i-9-central/penalties  -  It would seem you aren't liable/culpable.  This is a requirement of the employer, not the employee.

Comment: Maybe there are others in the group that are working illegally. If she files yours, that could raise questions about the other missing I99s.

Comment: If the employer took a shortcut with the I-9, I would assume that they took shorcuts with other forms as well (even if the W-4 was filled out, may be it wasn't submitted, or may be the incorrect amounts are being reported). If the employer is misreporting things to save money (or to delay payments), the employer is effectively stealing (or "borrowing") from the employee's future benefits. See https://www.irs.gov/uac/irs-warns-businesses-individuals-to-watch-for-questionable-employment-tax-practices or https://www.irs.gov/uac/employer-and-employee-responsibilities-employment-tax-enforcement

Comment: The I9 is an employer required form not an employee required form.  Let it go.  If you really want to cause trouble though, anonymously report the employer to ICE that they are not maintaining proper records.

Answer (score 4):

This is very dubious. I'm in the UK; my employer could get into massive trouble if they didn't check that I have permission to work for them (even if there was not the slightest doubt that you have permission, "not checking" would be trouble, and "not checking" and then it turned out I had no permission would be big trouble for them).

Now I could understand if someone wants to employ illegal workers and not fill out that form. But you told them that you have no problem filling out that form, and they still refuse, so I would be afraid that something deeper might be going on, and since we both don't know what that might be, I'd be very wary. I'd ask the same question on law.stackexchange: Just don't ask for legal advice, but whether anyone has an idea *why* your employer would do that.

If you want to be on the safe side, find out which government agency is responsible and ask them for advice. Which could get your manager in trouble, but that's her fault.

PS. If I understand Wesley's link right, not having you fill out the form means a fine of $110 to $1,100 for the employer, assuming you are entitled to work in the USA. Since you repeatedly asked them to fill out the form, if I had to set the fine I'd set it to the maximum.

I still cannot find any reason why she would refuse this - I would assume that she doesn't want any evidence that you are actually employed there; the other possibility is outright stupidity, or she suspects that you are not allowed to work there and wants to avoid evidence (which wouldn't help; not filling out the form for someone who isn't actually entitled gets a fine up to $16,000 in repeat cases).

mkennedy's comment (maybe there are others that are working illegally, and she's trying to cover up) would fall under criminal charges: "Engaging in a pattern or practice of hiring, recruiting or referring for a fee unauthorised aliens."